# Return a PrintDocument() as a PDF in web project

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf

I have an existing, and very complex, library that generates a System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument() that is used to send print jobs directly to a printer.

I now need to take this existing library and generate PDF documents for a web application.

I tried looking into 3rd party libraries such as ABCpdf, Spire.PDF, PDFSharp, etc, and none of them seem to be able to take a PrintDocument as input. At least none of their documentation indicated they could.

There are a couple of other questions here regarding this, but none of them point to an actual solution or library that works.

Installing a print driver such as Bullzip doesn't seem to be an option either as I need to return the rendered PDF through the web application.

What options are there for taking a PrintDocument(), rendering it as a PDF, and then serving it through a web application?